# pm2 Single Page Application flag --spa throws 'unknown option' error

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using `pm2` (5.1.2) and `serve` (13.0.2) to deploy a Node.js app. When I run the following:

`pm2 serve build 8080 --spa`

I receive the following error:

`error: unknown option '--spa'`

Is the flag deprecated? What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `pm2` there needs to be a space between `--` and flags. The correct format is:

`pm2 serve build 8080 -- spa`